# Is there an alternative to using lots of switch statements in a class?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Is there an alternative to using lots of switch statements?

I have a class which works on different pages, but does the same thing.
However each page has different data to load.
This is how I have been doing it (the colours are only for example only and are not really in my application).
I check the page in the constructor and put it in the $this->page variable. Then I would have a function like this.

```
private function loadTable(){
    switch($this->page){
        case "green":
            $check = $this->loadGreen();
            return $check;
        break;
        case "blue":
            $check = $this->loadBlue();
            return $check;
        break;
        case "orange":
            $check = $this->loadOrange();
            return $check;
        break;  
    }   
}
```

But then I might have another function which does something else like this:

```
public function searchRecord(){
    $name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['term']));
    switch($this->page){
        case "green":
            $query = "SELECT `green_ID`,Reason FROM `green`";
        break;
        case "blue":
            $query = "SELECT `blue_ID`,Reason FROM `blue`";
        break;
        case "orange":
            $query = "SELECT `orange_ID`,`colour`,`hat` FROM `orange`";
        break;
        default:
            return "";
    }
    //rest of code removed for sanity
}
```

You can see quite quickly with lots of functions I am going to end up with a lot of switch statements, and this is only for 3 pages. What if I had a hundred pages.

I thought about writing a function which has all the cases in for the whole page and sets a variable to say what page I am on, but that won't work because I would still need a switch to check that variable.

I want to be able to call a function and have that function do something different depending on what page I am on, but my current system is ending up with lots of switch statement which I would like to reduce if possible.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OOP correctly implemented is the solution for this problem. It is called [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping) and it's one kind of polymorphism.

You crammed the functionality of all your page types in a single class and that's why you ended up with lots of `switch` statements. Try to identify the differences between your page types and create one empty generic function for each functionality. Then extend the current page class and implement in each child class the functionality specific to one type of page.

Something like this:

```
abstract class Page
{
    abstract public function loadTable();
    abstract protected function getSearchQuery($term);

    public function searchRecord($term);
    {
        $query = $this->getSearchQuery($term);
        // rest of search code
    }
}

class GreenPage extends Page
{
    public function loadTable()
    {
        // move the code of function Page::loadGreen() here
    }

    protected function getSearchQuery($term)
    {
         return "SELECT `green_ID`,Reason FROM `green`";
    }
}   

class BluePage extends Page
{
    public function loadTable()
    {
        // move the code of function Page::loadBlue() here
    }

    protected function getSearchQuery($term)
    {
         return "SELECT `blue_ID`,Reason FROM `blue`";
    }
}
```

Then you probably need to create a Factory object; based on some characteristics you pass it, it knows how to create the correct type of `Page` object:

```
class PageFactory
{
    public function createPage($name)
    {
         switch ($name)
         {
         case 'green':
             return new GreenPage();
         case 'blue':
             return new BluePage();
         case 'red':
             return new RedPage();
         default:
             // this either should never happen or you have a type of page as default
         }
     }
}


$factory = new PageFactory();
$page = $factory->createPage($name);
$page->loadTable();
$page->searchRecord(trim($_POST['term']));
```

Comment: This sounds like a good plan, but not totally understanding how it works. So each page uses a different extended class and PageFactory redirects it to each class depending on page, but I am not sure what abstract class page is doing. A lot of things share common functions also. Would the common functions be put in page? This is similar to how you extend classes in C++. I think I will set up a test project to test this out.

Comment: I have just been reading about abstract classes. So as I understand it, an abstract class is a class inherited by another class. Which is what I thought an extended class was. Seems I have a lot to learn, but I am pretty sure this is the best answer.

Comment: An abstract class models a generic concept. In your example, the `Page` class models a generic page. It contains the operations common to all pages. It doesn't have to be abstract. If, for example, you can provide an implementation for the abstract functions that is valid for any page of your site then you can implement these functions (instead of declaring them abstract) and remove the `abstract` keyword from the class declaration. You can then use the `Page` class as default and use the specific `BluePage` or `GreenPage` for pages that have a different behaviour.

Comment: I have got it working in my main application now. I have put common functions in the abstract page class. The good thing about this new system is that I can now separate my classes into different files, which means I can work on each class without having to scroll through a lot of code. I have always used public and private not protected, but now if I want to make it public but not accessible I have made it protected. Thank you, you have helped me greatly.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your query without using a switch by just creating it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT `".$this->page."_ID`,Reason FROM `".$this->page."`";
```

Comment: assuming that $this->page is derived from user input, this answer opens a whole new realm of possible **SQL injections**

Comment: Yeh I understand this, but some of my queries might have a different number of items. Will update my example to show this.

Comment: what you could do is calling different functions, just like you do in example 1, so you wouldnt need so many switches. But personally i like calling the same function with different parameters. If that means having more switches then so be it. Maybe someone else has a better solution, idk.

Comment: What I have been doing is that if a function needs to be doing something totally different I have been loading it like example one, but if only one line needs changing I have been using example 2. However scalability to more pages is the problem with my current code

Answer (score 1):

how about storing your queries in an array and referencing it?

```
public function searchRecord() {
    $q = [  
            'blue' => 'SELECT `blue_ID`, Reason FROM `blue`',
            'orange' => 'SELECT `orange_ID`, `colour`, `hat` FROM `orange`'
            //....
        ];
    if(array_key_exists($this->page, $q)) {
        $query = $q[$this->page];

        //insert here the code you removed for sanity
    } else {
        //nothing found
        return "";
    }
}
```

that way, you can define one query for each page in just one line each.
if you define that query-array somewhere else, you won't even have to edit your *code* to add or edit a single page.

**edit:** another method for different functions

first, you define a provider class which contains one function for each page you want to serve:

```
class pageProvider {
    public static function red() {}
    public static function green() {}
    //....
}
```

and then you map your calls explicitely to that class:

```
function mapToClass($page) {
    $callback = ["pageProvider", $page];
    if(is_callable($callback)) {
        return call_user_func($callback);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

using user input to directly call code *could* lead to security holes if you let it roam free, but since we explicitely limit the calls to publicly available static methods of a defined class, it's not possible for an attacker to break out and do something bad.

see also:

- [is_callable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)
- [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: This sounds promising, but the problem there it isn't just the query string I have to worry about. As different tables have different field names so I would have to store them too, as I am using mysqli. However I have an idea where I can use your code elsewhere in my application

Comment: @ThomasWilliams well - you could use reflection methods to *map* your calls to a class, so if, for example, `$this->page == "red"`, your code calls `providerClass::red();`

Comment: I would like to see an example of this. Not heard of reflection methods before. I understand your meaning, but not how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly write classnames according to the colors:

    `public function searchRecordGreen()`

and call it via

    `searchRecord$color()`

Should work with php.

To make it more specific:

Php.net has an example:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    function Variable()
    {
       $name = 'Bar';
        $this->$name();      // This calls the Bar() method
    }

    function Bar()
    {
        echo "This is Bar";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$funcname = "Variable";
$foo->$funcname();  // This calls $foo->Variable()

?>
```

You could create a function with the names you want and use `$this->page` as a function name to save the exessive switch statements

Comment: The colours were only an example, but even if I called my classnames searchRecordGreen I would still need to use a switch to call it, and I have ended up with lots of functions with these switches in, and that is only with only 3 pages. There are no colours in my real code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do something like this:

```
private function loadTable(){

    /* define what pages are acceptable*/
    $acceptablePages = array('green','red','blue');

    /* check if this->page is of an acceptable value*/
    if(in_array($this->page,$acceptablePages)) {

        /* if it is acceptable then load a function with the page passed as a parameter*/
        return $this->loadColour($this->page);
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Problem is when I get to loadTable I would still need a switch statement to see if red green or blue was sent in. So we are replacing the switch statement here and just moving it to loadTable